# storing xml in azure table storage

Tags: c#, xml, azure

I have a very simple jobs table (currently in sql server) with the following fields: 
jobid - int type
details - xml type

I want to move all of this data from sql server to azure table storage. But I don't know how to store the xml data in table storage as I don't believe it supports XML. The app that I will create will only read the xml data - never update/delete it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to search on nodes in this XML document or do you want to store it as single XML document?

Comment: just storing the xml and displaying it. If I did want to search on the nodes what would I need to do and would azure table storage support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that `Azure Tables` does not have an XML data type. It does have `String` data type. What you could do is convert the XML data into string and then save the data. Please see sample code below:

```
    static void SaveDataInTable(int jobId, XDocument details)
    {
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        var client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = client.GetTableReference("MyTable");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();
        var entity = new DynamicTableEntity(partitionKey: "PK", rowKey: "RK");
        entity.Properties.Add("jobId", new EntityProperty(jobId));
        entity.Properties.Add("details", new EntityProperty(details.ToString()));//Convert XML to string
        var insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
        table.Execute(insertOperation);
    }
```